# Custom JobRepository in JBeret for Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, jsr352, jberet, jbatch

As described in [Quarkus JBeret documentation](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-jberet#configuration), it is possible to use `in-memory`or `jdbc` as values for`quarkus.jberet.repository`. I can see corresponding `io.quarkiverse.jberet.runtime.JBeretInMemoryJobRepositoryProducer`and `io.quarkiverse.jberet.runtime.JBeretJdbcJobRepositoryProducer` classes.

I would like to implement my own DynamoDB JobRepository and plug it in JBeret.
Is it possible to plug a custom JobRepository in JBeret?

I can see InfinispanRepository and MongoRepository exists (but not available in Quarkus). Is it possible to implement a DynamoDB based JobRepository?

Answer (score 1):

As of Quarkus JBeret 2.0.1, it's not possible for 2 reasons:

- The list of available JobRepositories is limited to jdbc/in-memory in [quarkus-jberet-deployment code](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-jberet/blob/2.0.1/core/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkiverse/jberet/deployment/JBeretProcessor.java#L119)
- The `org.jberet.repository.AbstractPersistentRepository` class is not designed to be extended: [abstract methods](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/blob/2.1.1.Final/jberet-core/src/main/java/org/jberet/repository/AbstractPersistentRepository.java#L43) are package-protected and can not be overriden outside of `org.jberet.repository` package.